# Fundamental Solution of Traveling Wave

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

So given the stationary equation for a traveling wave with wave-number *k*,
$-\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-{k^2g}=\delta(x-\xi)$ with $0<x,\xi<1$, how can I find a causal fundamental solution to this? I assume we can start by using the heuristic approach which after calculations would yield a causal solution *E*$(x,\xi)=u_{\xi}(x)H(x-\xi)$ where then we first find the solution $u_{\xi}$ to get *E*$(x,\xi)$. Also, since this is a causal solution we also know that *E*$(x,\xi)=0$ for $x<\xi$. This is pretty much what I can provide for my attempt for finding *E*$(x,\xi)$ but I am still new to this concept and I honestly don't know where to begin. It is also asked that a verification through differentiation (in the distributional sense) of the causal fundamental solution *E*$(x,\xi)$ can satisfy the original equation. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in distribution,

$$y''(x)=-k^2g$$

for $x\ne\xi$.  So, we have

$$y(x)=\begin{cases}
-\frac12 k^2g x^2+C_1x+C_2&, x<\xi\\\\
-\frac12 k^2g x^2+C_3 x+C_4&,x>\xi
\end{cases}$$

Now enforce continuity of $y(x)$ at $x=\xi$ and

$$y'(\xi^+)-y'(\xi^-)=-1$$

Comment: I see, but forgive me, I'm not completely sure on how this would yield a causal fundamental solution such as $E(x-\xi)$, and how can i find the constants with no given initial conditions?

Comment: You'll end up with the sum of a particular solution that has a unit step (aka Heaviside) function plus a homogeneous solution that has undetermined coefficients that would be determined by applying boundary conditions.